# Export default for shared Typescript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have some Typescript interfaces that are used in multiple modules throughout my app. Thought it was best to extract these to a `typings` folder and simple import them when I need them. One file looks like this:

*typings/sys.ts*

```
interface Sys {
  contentType: {
    sys: {
      id: string;
    };
  };
  id: string;
}

export default Sys;
```

This throws an ESLint error: `'Sys' is not defined.`.

If I change the file to:

```
export default interface Sys {
  contentType: {
    sys: {
      id: string;
    };
  };
  id: string;
}
```

I get an ESLint error about a missing semicolon at the end. If I add the semi colon I get both a missing semi colon error and an unnecessary semi colon error!!

What is the correct way to structure types like this so they are reusable in multiple modules, with the correct syntax that will keep ESLint happy?

Comment: if you get the semicolon warning - either put the semicolon at the end or turn that rule off - there's no third option.

Comment: Putting the semicolon at the end gives the warning of unnecessary semicolon. Interfaces are set to not need semi colon at end through my ESLint config, but I'm guessing default exports do need it. My question is really whether this overall solution is a standard approach to shared interfaces, and if so, if it's OK to just have 1 interface in the file and export it as default.

Comment: Use TSLint, because ESLint was originally made for JS (not TS) linting, so that's may be the cause of your problem. TSLint have a lot of rules as well.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev TSLint advise is to start using ESLint instead. I think they will stop support for it soon.

Comment: @Coop hmm.. didn't know that.. Anyway, it seems that JSLint has started their TS support just [a few months ago](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) so there still have to be many issues. BTW is it that you should add `"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"` to `.eslintrc.json` file? I don't know